# Node.js Redis client get method error when Redis server is down

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using node-redis version `3.0.2`. However, I was checking how my website will respond if the Redis server is down. I have this request handler where It calls a function that checks first if the provided key is in Redis, else make a database call and then save the fetched data in Redis.

```
const GetByPriority = model => async (req, res) => {
    let { page=1, size=9 } = req.query;
    size = parseInt(size);
    page = parseInt(page);
    try {
        const doc = await SetOrGetCompanyCache(`companies-${page}-${size}`, async () => {
            const query = await model
                .find({})
                .limit(size*1)
                .skip((page-1)*size)
                .sort({ p: -1, _id:1 })
                .lean()
                .exec()
            return query;
        })
        if (!doc)
        {
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        res.status(200).json({page:page, size:size, data: doc })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        res.status(400).end()
    }
}
```

The problem is when the Redis server is down, there does not seem to be an error returned by `redisClient`'s get method. I mean I don't get why it did not log the error. Also, It did not return `InternalServerError`.

```
export function SetOrGetCompanyCache (key, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        redisClient.get(key, async (error,data)=>{
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error) //It does not get here
                return reject(createError.InternalServerError('Caching Error'))
            }
            //Cache hit
            if(data != null)
            {
                return resolve(JSON.parse(data))
            }
            //Cache miss
            //callback() --> MongoDB query
            const queryData = await callback();
            if(!queryData)
            {
                return reject(createError[404])
            }
            redisClient.setex(key,COMPANY_QUERY_EXP,JSON.stringify(queryData))
            resolve(queryData)
        })
    })
}
```

It only logged the following snippet

```
Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I believe this is because I added the following listener inside `redisClient` file

```
redisClient.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.error(err.message)
})
```

The problem now is that the `set` method does not return any error indicating that the Redis server is down, hence I can't even make the server perform a normal database call in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the `redis` community on discord and they mentioned that I should set `enable-offline-queue` to `false` inside `redis-client`

It should look like this

```
export const redisClient  = createClient({
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    //In order to turn off queuing commands and get an error if we couldn't connect to the redis server
    enable_offline_queue: false
});
```

As they mentioned

> In Node Redis, if you handle add the on('error') stuff it will queue
> up your commands and then in the background try to reconnect. When it
> does reconnect, it will then run the queued commands. [7:30 PM] It
> actually follows a retry_strategy to attempt to reconnect. You can
> read all about it on the old README at
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis/v/3.1.2 npm redis A modern, high
> performance Redis client. Latest version: 4.0.4, last published: 24
> days ago. Start using redis in your project by running `npm i redis`.
> There are 8235 other projects in the npm registry using redis.
>
> [7:31 PM] You need to set the enable_offline_queue option to false to
> turn off this queueing and get an error.